# Unable to locate Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, homebrew, apple-m1

After running `brew install openjdk && brew install openjdk@11`, I installed scala and spark through brew. When I tried opening the scala shell using scala, it just gave me:

```
User@My-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % scala 
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

And the same error when I try `java -version`.

However, I'm able to open the spark shell. What could be the reason for this, and how would I fix it?

Comment: Have you defined a JAVA_HOME env variable ?

Comment: It's currently set to /usr/bin/java, but I'm guessing that's wrong?

Comment: Well, is there a java at /usr/bin/java ?

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, I solved it by simply downloading the latest Java 8 dmg from the [java website](https://www.java.com/en/download/) and installing it.

Comment: Which dmg exactly? It is great that you want to help future readers with the same problem, but then: you need to be much more explicit. Your answer is close to useless for other people. And note: answers are expected to be just that: answers. Ending them with a question defeats the point. If you have a new question, ask a new **question**.

Comment: I've edited the answer - it's just the latest Java 8 dmg . Thanks for your comment, I'll keep this in mind in the future as well

Comment: There are many different java runtime flavors, and so many sites. Why don't you just provide the exact link, too?